# QtRuby cannot create QDate to populate QDateEdit

Tags: mysql, ruby, qt, qtruby

I'm using QtRuby + Mysql2 in a project, and i'm trying to retrieve all the data I need to populate the form.

First, a query is made. Then, each value is taken and used to fill each related widget.

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "", :database => "school")
res= client.query("SELECT * FROM activ WHERE act_name = '#{@cActiv.currentText()}' ")
res.each do |row|
            @tName.setText(row['act_name'].to_s)
            @tType.setText(row['act_type'].to_s)
            @strDate= row['act_date'].to_s
            @year=@strDate[0,4].to_i
            @month=@strDate[5,2].to_i
            @day=@strDate[7,2].to_i
            @date= Qt::Date.new(@year, @month, @day)
            @deDate.setDate(@date)
end
```

The Problem is that I've got an error when trying to set the date to the DateEdit, even when the QDate object was created with no error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know ruby, but I think that it can be very helpful to others if you tell us which error you get.

Comment: Sorry. It's "undefined method 'setDate' for QtDateEdit". setDate needs a Qt::Date as argument, and a Qt::Date needs three integers as arguments, so that's when I get lost and don't see where is the error in the code above. One more thing: printing the value of @date before the setDate, throws this: #<Qt::Date:0xf140e8> ; so I guess it's a Qt::Date after all, but just cannot use it for setting the date of the QtDateEdit (really confusing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not within the shown code fragment. Either `@year`, `@month`, or `@day` do not receive valid values from the string conversions, or `@deDate` is not a `Qt::DateEdit`.